# How to report bug in groovy

Tags: groovy

these piece of code:

```
if (false)
    int number = 0

1..3.each{
    println number
}

return bug:
```

BUG! exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit 'Script7.groovy' tried to get a variable with the name number as stack variable, but a variable with this name was not created

How I can report this bug to developer of groovy  to fix it ? I am using version 1.8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can report Groovy bugs on their [public JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/GROOVY/issues)

Posting to the groovy-user mailing list is probably a good idea too, explaining the issue and with a link to the JIRA report you created.

Btw:  This also fails on Groovy 1.8.6 (it's always worth checking the latest version of Groovy, as it might have been fixed)

---

I guess even with the fix in place, this will still fail (but not with a `BUG!` failure).  To get it to work, you would need to do:

```
int number = 1

if (false)
    number = 0

(1..3).each{
    println number
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx I think that this jira is just for developer not for public. I know where is the problem but thx anyway

Comment: @hudi No, anyone can sign up, and create a bug report.  Click `Log In`, then click `Sign Up`

Comment: yes I do: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5466  but this is very dangerous for spammer :)

Comment: Update link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-5466